# Capturing UITextField tap before didBeginEditing is called

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextfield

I have a unique UI situation where I need to handle a tap event differently than what I could do with didBeginEditing. In some situations, text fields gain focus programmatically but users can still manually set focus by tapping the text field.

There is a notification that fires whenever the keyboard comes into view, but I would like the code fired by this notification to execute ONLY if a user taps the text field and NOT when focus is set in code.

Notification declaration:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:self.view.window];
```

Method fired by notification:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    CGSize kbSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, kbSize.height / 3, 0);
    [_tableView setContentInset:contentInsets];
    [_tableView setScrollIndicatorInsets:contentInsets];
}
```

So I guess what I'm having trouble with is making these four lines of code fire only from a tap event and I haven't found a way to get the keyboard size without a notification. Any suggestions?

Comment: it is not possible by textfield delegate method but if it necessary requirement for you then do one thing put UITapGestureRecognizer on your text field

Comment: I would rather go with hitTest:withEvent: or more precisely pointInside:withEvent: to indicate what is happening before any gesture recognizer or touches methods will fire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the textFieldShouldBeginEditing method and return true if you need it to become the first responder. So it will be:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    //Your code
    return true;
}
```